# how/when is a static variable in a function declared within C language?

Tags: c, static, initialization

My question is in the `foo()` function, the `sa` variable seems to be declared and initialized there, however since it is static is it ignored by the compiler after the first time? How come it is not initialized back to the value 10 even if it's static?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo()
{
int a = 10;
static int sa = 10;

a += 5;
sa += 5;

printf("a = %d, sa = %d\n", a, sa);
}


int main()
{
int i;

for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    foo();
}
```

This prints:

```
a = 15, sa = 15
a = 15, sa = 20
a = 15, sa = 25
a = 15, sa = 30
a = 15, sa = 35
a = 15, sa = 40
a = 15, sa = 45
a = 15, sa = 50
a = 15, sa = 55
a = 15, sa = 60
```

Comment: Please reread what the static keyword means

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program would work identically if you declared `sa` globally, though its scope would be different:

```
int sa = 10;

void foo()
{
    int a = 10;

    a += 5;
    sa += 5;

    printf("a = %d, sa = %d\n", a, sa);
}
```

The reason you might want to declare `sa` within `foo` is to limit its access.

Answer (score 2):

In C, `static` means that it persists between calls, so it is the opposite of what you suggest: the initialization *only* occurs on the first call.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting `C11` standard, chapter §6.2.4, *Storage durations of objects*

> An object whose identifier is declared without the storage-class specifier
>   `_Thread_local`, and either with external or internal linkage or with the storage-class
>   specifier `static`, has static storage duration. Its lifetime is the entire execution of the
>   program and its stored value is initialized only once, prior to program startup.

So, `sa` is not being initialized on every call. It is initialized only once and holds the last stored value.

That said, regarding the *retention* of the value, quoting the same spec,

> [..] An object exists, has a constant address, and retains
>   its last-stored value throughout its lifetime. [...]

The reason of putting it inside a function is to limit the scope of the variable to that function scope itself.

Answer (score 0):

`static` can declare a function which is only visible within the compilation unit.

This use of `static` variables within a function,
a) reserves a piece of memory which will hold the single value (irrespective of threads), and
b) Initialize it only once.  In `C++11` this is guaranteed to be thread safe, although I don't think there is such a guarantee in `C`.

So there is a single piece of memory reserved.  Until the function is called, it will not be setup

Answer (score 0):

Objects with `static` storage duration are allocated and initialized *once* at program startup, and that storage is held until the program terminates.

Thus, the `sa` variable is allocated and initialized when the program starts, not when `foo` is first executed, and it persists between calls to `foo`.

The `sa` variable is only visible by name within the `foo` function, however.